# SQL query to return all media of specific user and check if friend has seen the media

Tags: mysql, sql

Media Table:

| id | user_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 10 |
| 5 | 5 |
| 6 | 7 |
| 7 | 7 |
| 8 | 1 |
| 9 | 2 |
| 10 | 2 |
| 11 | 1 |
| 12 | 8 |
| 13 | 2 |

Seen Table:

| id | user_id | media_id | friend_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 2 | 5 |
| 2 | 2 | 3 | 5 |
| 3 | 2 | 10 | 10 |
| 4 | 10 | 7 | 5 |
| 5 | 2 | 13 | 5 |
| 6 | 7 | 24 | 7 |
| 7 | 7 | 23 | 9 |
| 8 | 1 | 26 | 1 |
| 9 | 7 | 22 | 2 |
| 10 | 9 | 19 | 2 |
| 11 | 1 | 22 | 2 |
| 12 | 8 | 20 | 2 |
| 13 | 20 | 14 | 5 |

Result I want:

| user_id | media_id | friend_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 | NULL |
| 2 | 2 | 5 |
| 2 | 3 | 5 |
| 2 | 9 | NULL |
| 2 | 10 | NULL |
| 2 | 13 | 5 |

My current query is this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM media
  LEFT JOIN seen ON seen.media_id=media.id
WHERE media.user_id = 2
UNION
SELECT *
  FROM media
  RIGHT JOIN seen ON seen.media_id=media.id
WHERE media.user_id = 2;
```

But this query is missing a condition for friend_id = 5 (I cannot figure this out).

Basically what I want to do is get all rows from Media Table where user_id = 2 and check friend_id = 5 from Seen Table for the specific user_id (2) and their media_id.

Comment: Skip the UNION. Instead do another JOIN.

Comment: Can u explain me how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by only joing the tables once, but you need to psecify the on clause with the wanted ids

> ```
> CREATE TABLE Media  (
>   `id` INTEGER,
>   `user_id` INTEGER
> );
>
> INSERT INTO Media 
>   (`id`, `user_id`)
> VALUES
>   ('1', '2'),
>   ('2', '2'),
>   ('3', '2'),
>   ('4', '10'),
>   ('5', '5'),
>   ('6', '7'),
>   ('7', '7'),
>   ('8', '1'),
>   ('9', '2'),
>   ('10', '2'),
>   ('11', '1'),
>   ('12', '8'),
>   ('13', '2');
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE Seen  (
>   `id` INTEGER,
>   `user_id` INTEGER,
>   `media_id` INTEGER,
>   `friend_id` INTEGER
> );
>
> INSERT INTO Seen 
>   (`id`, `user_id`, `media_id`, `friend_id`)
> VALUES
>   ('1', '2', '2', '5'),
>   ('2', '2', '3', '5'),
>   ('3', '2', '10', '10'),
>   ('4', '10', '7', '5'),
>   ('5', '2', '13', '5'),
>   ('6', '7', '24', '7'),
>   ('7', '7', '23', '9'),
>   ('8', '1', '26', '1'),
>   ('9', '7', '22', '2'),
>   ('10', '9', '19', '2'),
>   ('11', '1', '22', '2'),
>   ('12', '8', '20', '2'),
>   ('13', '20', '14', '5'),
>   ('14','2','2', '4');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT m.user_id, m.id as media_id, s.friend_id 
> FROM Media m LEFT JOIN Seen s ON s.user_id = m.user_id AND m.id = s.media_id AND s.friend_id = 5
> WHERE m.user_id = 2
> ```
>
> ```
> user_id | media_id | friend_id
> ------: | -------: | --------:
>       2 |        1 |      null
>       2 |        2 |         5
>       2 |        3 |         5
>       2 |        9 |      null
>       2 |       10 |      null
>       2 |       13 |         5
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6d8352103efc4de2a2de5bbdc28ecf0d)*

Comment: Yes, this query gets the desired result.